# Using Handlebars #each helper with no key in JSON

Tags: json, handlebars.js

I am using a PHP file to pull data from a database and return it as JSON. I want to then use the JSON data as the context for a Handlebars template. My problem is that I can't seem to get Handlebars' "{{#each}}" helper to work with the JSON being returned by the PHP file.

Here is an example of the JSON that is returned:

```
[
    {
        "id": "3",
        "type": "Abseiling",
        "title": "Abseiling Adventure",
        "location": "Glenrock State Conservation Area",
        "date": "2012-12-18 00:00:00",
        "length": "2 hours",
        "price": "50"
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "type": "Abseiling",
        "title": null,
        "location": "Glenrock State Conservation Area",
        "date": "2013-02-10 00:00:00",
        "length": "3 hours",
        "price": "70"
    }
]
```

Here is my Handlebars template:

```
{{#each}}
<p>{{location}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

I have also tried:

```
{{#each}}
<p>{{this.location}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

My suspicion as to why this isn't working is that the #each helper cannot be run like I'm trying, but rather has to be called like so: {{#each something}}. If this is the case, is there any easy way to add a key to the JSON data so that it is in this form:

```
something: [
    {
        ...
    },
    {
        ...
    }
]
```

If my suspicion is wrong, how can I use the #each helper with the JSON I'm currently providing as the template context?

**UPDATE:** Found a solution for this problem, I simply had to change the template call from

```
jQuery(".events").html(Handlebars.templates['Events'](data));
```

to

```
jQuery(".events").html(Handlebars.templates['Events']({events: data}));
```

Which meant I could then use {{#each events}}.

Comment: You can put your **UPDATE** down as an answer and accept that answer (but I think you need to wait 24 hours to accept your own answer), might help people searching for similar things in the future. Handlebars needs to refer to things by name in the template, the object argument to the template function is essentially a little portable namespace that allows you to give your `data` a name.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem and solved it with the use of the '**this**' keyword.

```
{{#each this}}
  <p>{{this.location}}</p>
{{/each}}
```